# Udacity Firebase tutorial - implementing Firebase UI list adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listadapter, firebaseui

I 'm stuck with implementing the FireBase UI ListAdapter in the Udacity Firebase course. The whole stuff has changed a lot and now the ActiveListAdapter.java throws error:

> Cannot resolve method 'super(andoid.app.Activity, java.lang.Class, int, com.google.firebase.database.Query)'

Has anyone encountered this issue? Do you know how to resolve it?

this is my ActiveListAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.udacity.firebase.shoppinglistplusplus.R;
import com.udacity.firebase.shoppinglistplusplus.model.ShoppingList;

/**
 * Populates the list_view_active_lists inside ShoppingListsFragment
 */
public class ActiveListAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<ShoppingList> {

    /**
     * Public constructor that initializes private instance variables when adapter is created
     */
    public ActiveListAdapter(Activity activity, Class<ShoppingList> modelClass, int modelLayout,
                             Query ref) {
        super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * Protected method that populates the view attached to the adapter (list_view_active_lists)
     * with items inflated from single_active_list.xml
     * populateView also handles data changes and updates the listView accordingly
     */

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, ShoppingList list, int i) {
        /**
         * Grab the needed Textivews and strings
         */
        TextView textViewListName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_list_name);
        TextView textViewCreatedByUser = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_created_by_user);


        /* Set the list name and owner */
        textViewListName.setText(list.getListName());
        textViewCreatedByUser.setText(list.getOwner());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete error logs?

Comment: It is: Cannot resolve method 'super(andoid.app.Activity, java.lang.Class<com.udacity.firebase.shoppinglistplusplus.model.ShoppingList>, int, com.google.firebase.database.Query)'

Comment: Can you show how you include FirebaseUI in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

This may be happening because you are using latest firebase UI library that has been updated to work with firebase library 9.2.1 while your client library is still old.

'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'

You have to use latest client library and update your queries accordingly.

Refer to the following link:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

In ShoppingListsFragment, my queries were based on old firebase client library and created a similar issue. After updated them, everything started working!

'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

Answer (score 0):

@Egor is right. Your constructor should look like below:

```
public ActiveListAdapter(Activity activity, Class<ShoppingList> modelClass, int modelLayout,
                         Query ref) {
    super(ref, modelClass, modelLayout, activity);
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but now resolved by making few changes.
In the build.gradle file I changed the versions
1) compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'
and
2) compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
(You will need to change other firebase versions also to 9.2.0 in the build.gradle)
Changed the import command to
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
Earlier it was 
import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;